# View category in the preview of Theme Customizer

Tags: categories, customization, theme-customizer, previews

I am building a theme which Theme customizer changes colors, sizes, etc. and has also the option to choose a category and style that category specifically.

How can I display that category in the preview (only when the user is changing the corresponding options) instead of the default home/front page displayed by default?

**EDIT**

I can access the preview window with [customize_preview_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_preview_init), but I can not apply [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect), which I guess could be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

1.Require an extra file that will contain the hooks only in the theme preview

```
function mytheme_customizer_live_preview() {
    require_once('library/preview.php');
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'mytheme_customizer_live_preview' );
```

2.What I had to do is modify the query as I would normally do in the page, so just do it in the preview (inside preview.php):

```
function modify_query($query) {

    $category = get_theme_mod( 'mytheme' )['categories'][0];

    $query->set('cat', $category);

    return $query;

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'modify_query', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you goal correctly, then will you a select inside the Customizer, there list the Categories and the User can use this for save in your theme settings.

If you will enhance the Customizer for categories, then use [this class](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Theme-Customizer-Custom-Controls/blob/master/category_dropdown_custom_control.php) from this repo here. Include the file and enhacne the default class. You can easy implement a select for the categories of the install. Inside the [readme](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Theme-Customizer-Custom-Controls) of this repo are two links to gist with a example use, but for other class of the repo. I think is clear and the same way on all extensions for the Customizer.

Comment: I have the way to create a category dropdown selection. My doubt is with the next step. How to show that category in the preview window. So normally it shows www.example.com and i want to show www.example.com/category/whatever in the preview window (using php)

Comment: If you use the class, then was the preview also in the customizer. Alternative you must add this to the js, thet create the preview, with ajax. Also [here](https://github.com/bueltge/Documentation/blob/master/js/theme-customizer.dev.js) a example. that create a fast preview of title and description.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I used to show things to users while they are viewing the site through the Theme Customizer previewer:

```
global $wp_customize;
if( is_user_logged_in() && isset($wp_customize) ) {
  // Show "categories" or things in the Customizer Previewer only
}
```

It makes your templates a bit more messy but, as you've probably discovered, there isn't much documentation/development on Theme customizer :/

Comment: But what Im looking is for that // Show "categories" or things in the Customizer Previewer only. I can manage to apply things only to the theme customizer preview window, but I hope there is some way to alter the preview url. (Javascript could be a way but I was looking for php solution). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add a javascript that activating only in live preview and redirect:
http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-redirect-web-page/

as advanced solution, you can create asynchronously working js function with using wp.customize. You can inspect my theme http://theme.firmasite.com/ for example usage.